# Prevent parsing of shortcodes inside code blocks

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I want to write a tutorial about [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/documentation/), so I write a [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#example-ref-and-relref-input) syntax in markdown, but I don't want to render it; I want it as normal text.

```
{{< ref "/page/about" >}}
```

When I run `hugo server`, it shows me: *page not found*, so obviously, it treats it as a shortcode.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to adds `/* */` in your shortcode and down. For example,

```
{{</* ref "/page/about" */>}}
```